# Sklearn model, The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, tree

I have been learning about decision trees and how to make them in sklearn. But when I have tried it out I have been unsuccessful in all my attempts to avoid a vlaue error that reads

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"
here is the full error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15136/2104431115.py in <module>
      2 dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth= 5, random_state= 1, min_samples_leaf=.1)
      3 dt.fit(x_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train.reshape(-1,1))
----> 4 y_pred = dt.predict(x_test, y_test)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in predict(self, X, check_input)
    465         """
    466         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 467         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
    468         proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
    469         n_samples = X.shape[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    430     def _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input):
    431         """Validate the training data on predict (probabilities)."""
--> 432         if check_input:
    433             X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    434             if issparse(X) and (

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and here is all of my code so far for this model:

```
x = np.array(bat[["TB_x"]])
y = np.array(bat[["TB_y"]])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= .2, random_state= 1)
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth= 5, random_state= 1, min_samples_leaf=.1)
dt.fit(x_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_pred = dt.predict(x_test, y_test)
```

origonally I was getting an error that would say that it was expecting a 2d array but wass getting a 1d array, I solved that problem by using reshape but now I get this value error that I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight misunderstanding about how the `predict` function works. If you think about it conceptually, if you are trying to predict something, why would you need to pass in the expected labels?

In a `DecisionTreeRegressor` (and in probably all sklearn models) the signature of `predict` is `predict(X, check_input=True)`, you only need to pass in the features, not the expected labels.

You are doing `y_pred = dt.predict(x_test, y_test)` but the second argument that `predict` expects is actually just a boolean that allows you to disable some sanity checks about `x_test`.

You just need to do the following instead:

```py
y_pred = dt.predict(x_test)
```

You can refer to the [sklearn documentation for a DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.predict) for more info